# Can't install Flutter in a certain folder

Tags: flutter, windows-10

I have a folder "C:\Program Files (Manual Install)" where I put programs that aren't installed automatically in the other Program Files folders. So that's where I want to install Flutter.

I cd in and run the git clone command which runs perfectly fine and installs it. However when I run "Flutter Doctor" (or any Flutter command) I get the error "\flutter\bin\cache was unexpected at this time."

I tried it in my Documents folder and it worked fine, however I don't want it there.

I've tried changing permissions and ownership and all sorts of the folder yet it's just not working. I've restarted and deleted the Flutter folder many times.

Comment: follow [those steps](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows)

Comment: I have followed those steps. Like I said it works in my documents folder.

Comment: Which location did you install it. post the path

Comment: The path where I installed it is the first line of my post?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the Flutter folder and download the SDK again and check your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the cache folder inside **bin**

> \flutter\bin\cache

and try again. It'll work.

Also you should run cmd / power-shell as admin.
Try changing the path of flutter from C:/Program files/

Comment: @TristanKing post a screenshot

Comment: Screenshot of what? It's a one line error which I typed in the question.